# Find overlap interval through query

Tags: sql, mysql, presto

I have the following table_1 which shows the time each person in Room_A.

| person | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 5 | 16 |
| Mary | 7 | 10 |
| Peter | 8 | 12 |

Then I want to have an output table which shows the time and the people in the Room_A, like:

| people | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [John] | 5 | 7 |
| [John, Mary] | 7 | 8 |
| [John, Mary, Peter] | 8 | 10 |
| [John, Peter] | 10 | 12 |
| [John] | 12 | 16 |

I am wondering if this is something achievable using SQL/Presto query ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the idea being to JOIN with the generated list of all possible intervals:

```
with rooms(person, start_time, end_time) as (
        select 'John', 5, 16 from dual union all
        select 'Mary', 7, 10 from dual union all
        select 'Peter', 8, 12 from dual -- union all
    )
    , times(hour) as (
        select start_time from rooms
        union
        select end_time from rooms
    )
    , intervals(start_time, end_time) as (
        select hour as start_time, lead(hour) over(order by hour) as end_time
        from times
    )
    select start_time, end_time, group_concat(person order by person) as persons
    from (
        select p2.person, 
            p1.start_time,
            p1.end_time
        from intervals p1
        join rooms p2 on 
            greatest(p1.start_time, p2.start_time) < least(p1.end_time, p2.end_time)
    ) t
    group by start_time, end_time
    ;

5   7   John
7   8   John,Mary
8   10  John,Mary,Peter
10  12  John,Peter
12  16  John
```

Comment: p3consulting thank you for the solution.i have a small request-could you please explain the logic behind that join - greatest(p1.start_time, p2.start_time) < least(p1.end_time, p2.end_time)
Thank you

Comment: One of the way to detect intersection of intervals

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following (untested) query:

```
WITH numbers AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SEQUENCE(1, 100)) AS number
) 
SELECT
    people,
    min(number) AS starts_time,
    max(number) AS end_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        n.number,
        array_join(t.person, ',') AS people
    FROM table_1 AS t 
    INNER JOIN numbers AS n ON n.number BETWEEN t.start_time AND t.end_time
    GROUP BY n.number
) AS p
GROUP BY people
ORDER BY people
```

I have the equivalent query operating (in Postgres) here: https://dbfiddle.uk/n6b28oZb and the query above is (I believe) suitable for Presto

| people | starts_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 5 | 16 |
| John,Mary | 7 | 7 |
| John,Mary,Peter | 8 | 10 |
| John,Peter | 11 | 12 |

But I have just noticed it isn't a full match to your wanted result